# Replace certain values of dataframe with values in another dataframe, based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

```
> df <- data.frame(id=c(015,335,625,789), B=c(8,19,8,6), C=c(4,1,4,6), Source=c("Gk", "Ap", "Ap", "Kh"))

> df

  id  B C Source
1 015  8 4     Gk
2 335 19 1     Ap
3 625  8 4     Ap
4 789  6 6     Kh
```

And another dataframe:

```
p <- data.frame(id=c(335,625, 789), B2 = c(5,3,4))
p

  id B2
1 335  5
2 625  3
3 789  4
```

I want replace those values in column `B` of `df` by the values in `B2` of `p`, but only for those with same `id` in both dataframes and `df$Source == "Ap"`.

The final dataframe should be:

```
  id  B C Source
1 015  8 4     Gk
2 335  5 1     Ap
3 625  3 4     Ap
4 789  6 6     Kh
```

I know how to replace the whole column by zeros or `NA`s, etc, but I just want to replace those that follow the mentioned condition (and without for loops...). How can I achieve this?

Comment: in `df` your id is not the same as `id` as in the definition of `df`. Please edit this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is ,

```
df[df$Source == "Ap", "B"] <- p[p$id %in% df[df$Source == "Ap", "id"] , "B2"]


#   id B C Source
#1  15 8 4     Gk
#2 335 5 1     Ap
#3 625 3 4     Ap
#4 789 6 6     Kh
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!